# Concatenate Strings with Spaces into a varchar(255) column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing an ETL logic to insert four source columns at a certain position of a certain length into a target `varchar(255)` column. I have tried several ways but unable to find a solution for it. Any help is much appreciated.

Ex:

Source:

```
Column_id at Column 14, len 8 
+ 
name at Column 43, len 27
+ 
term at Column 133, len 1
```

Target:

```
Description varchar(255)
```

Comment: I don't think you can do exactly that directly. I would get the value, then do the replacements and update it. I think you could use `SUBSTRING` or `STUFF`. Could the column be empty or shorter?

Comment: You mentioned 4 columns but the description in question talks about 3 columns. The above comment from Andrew is correct way of doing it. Look up SUBSTRING function of tsql it takes starting position and length as arguments which is suitable for fixed length flat files

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the data to char like this:

```
select REPLICATE(' ', 14)+convert(char(8), column_id)+REPLICATE(' ', 43-8-14) + convert(char(27), name) + REPLICATE(' ', 133-43-27)+convert(char(1), term)
from <whatever table not provided>
```

I left '133-43-27' as a example, test it so it's the right position...

Comment: I assume he needs the rest of the positions unchanged, and not full of spaces.

Comment: He can replace the replicate part with a substring function and get the result...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along this:

a *declared table* to simulate your issue

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT IDENTITY, [name] VARCHAR(100), term VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Name One','first term')
                      ,('One more name','One more term');
```

-- some variables for a generic approach

```
DECLARE @posId INT=1
       ,@posName INT=10
       ,@posTerm INT=50;
```

--the query

```
SELECT t.*
      ,STUFF(
       STUFF(
       STUFF(trg,@posId,   LEN(t.id),     t.id)
                ,@posName, LEN(t.[name]), t.[name])
                ,@posTerm, LEN(t.term),   t.term)
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT REPLICATE(' ',255)) A(trg)
```

--the result

```
1        Name One                                first term                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2        One more name                           One more term
```

The idea in short:

- First we use `CROSS APPLY(SELECT ...)` to add a column to our result set. This column is a string, created off 255 blanks.
- Now we can use `STUFF()`. This functions *stuffs* given characters into an existing string. By replacing the exact count of characters we will not touch the total length.

Hint 1: If your data might have trailing blanks `LEN()` can trick you out. You can either use `TRIM()` (older versions `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()`) or `DATALENGTH()` (be aware of 2 bytes with `NVARCHAR`!) then...

Hint 2: If you have to *cut* your data to a max length, you can use `LEFT()`

Answer (score 0):

`STUFF()` does what you want.  But you want to be really careful about overwriting all the data that is there.  For that, I would suggest casting to a `char()` type:

```
SELECT t.*,
       STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(target, 14, 8, CONVERT(CHAR(8), t.id
                        ), 43, 27, CONVERT(CHAR(27), t.name
                  ), 133, 1, CONVERT(CHAR(1), t.term
            )
FROM t;
```

The `CHAR()` type pads the values with spaces, which means that this code will overwrite any existing data in those positions (and only in those positions).